# f.write to kml files

Tags: python, gis, kml

So, I've been tasked with writing kml files from phython, without using simplekml. I going wrong in the code... can anyone please identify the mistake?

```
#Input the file name."XYpoints1_wgs84"
fname = input("Enter file name WITHOUT extension: ")
data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')

#Skip the 1st header row.
#data.next()
#Open the file to be written.
f = open('Buffered_kml.kml', 'w')

#Writing the kml file.
f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>\n")
f.write("   <name>" + fname + '.kml' +"</name>\n")
f.write("   <Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing>\n")
f.write("           <coordinates>\n" )
next(data)
for row in data:
    f.write(str((row[1])) + "," + (str(row[2]))+"\n") 
f.write("           </coordinates>\n" )
f.write("   </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon> \n")
f.write("</kml>\n")
print ("File Created. ")
print ("Press ENTER to exit. ")
input()
f.close()
```

It does produce kml file but without the coordinate end tag. Why is this happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem -- if I provide the code with some sample data, it correctly writes the `</coordinates>` end tag. This shouldn't be the problem, but If I were writing this code, I would place the call to `f.close()` *before* the `print("File created.")` line (actually, I would use a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) block instead of having an explicit `close` statement).

Comment: Can you open it up on google earth?

Comment: I don't know. I'm just saying I can't reproduce the problem you describe in your question.

Comment: Looking at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#polygons it looks like you should have an outer `<Placemark>...</Placemark>` container.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the current question. Yes I did add placemark tag.. but still not seeing the polygon. I've opened up a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179921/i-cant-see-the-polygon-in-google-earth.... please answer my question here.