# I can't see the polygon in google earth

Tags: python, gis, kml, arcgis, qgis

Here is the code I'm using to generate .kml file:

```
def kmlForLab2():
    #XYpoints1_wgs84
    #XYpoints1_wgs84.csv
    
    #Input the file name."JoeDupes3_forearth"
    fname = input("Enter file name WITHOUT extension: ")
    data = csv.reader(open(fname + '.csv'), delimiter = ',')
    
    #Skip the 1st header row.
    #data.next()
    #Open the file to be written.
    f = open('Buffered_kml.kml', 'w')
    
    #Writing the kml file.
    f.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n")
    f.write("<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0'>\n")
    f.write("<Document>\n")
    f.write("<!-- first buffer -->")
    f.write("<Placemark>\n")
    f.write("   <name>" + fname + '.kml' +"</name>\n")
    f.write("   <Polygon> <outerBoundaryIs> <LinearRing>\n")
    f.write("           <coordinates>\n" )
    next(data)
    for row in data:
        f.write(str((row[1])) + "," + " "+ (str(row[2]))+"\n") 
    f.write("           </coordinates>\n" )
    f.write("   </LinearRing> </outerBoundaryIs> </Polygon> \n")
    f.write("</Placemark>\n")
    f.write("</Document>\n")
    f.write("</kml>\n")
    f.close()
    print ("File Created. ")
    print ("Press ENTER to exit. ")
```

It generates .kml file but it dosen't zoom into the polygon within NZ. Whats happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<coordinates>` section of your document is meant to contain comma separated tuples, with each tuple separated from the next by whitespace.  So like this:

```
-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
-77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100
```

Or:

```
-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100 -77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100
```

Your code is inserting whitespace in the middle of a coordinate tuple. Given input like this:

```
unknown column,lat,lon,ele
1,-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
2,-77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703,100
3,-77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386,100
4,-77.05552622493516,38.868757801256,100
5,-77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943,100
6,-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824,100
```

Your code generates the following `<coordinates>` section:

```
<coordinates>
-77.05788457660967, 38.87253259892824
-77.05465973756702, 38.87291016281703
-77.05315536854791, 38.87053267794386
-77.05552622493516, 38.868757801256
-77.05844056290393, 38.86996206506943
-77.05788457660967, 38.87253259892824
</coordinates>
```

This does not display correctly. But if we modify your code so that it
looks like this:

```
    for row in data:
        f.write(str((row[1])) + "," + (str(row[2]))+"\n")
```

Or using `join` like this:

```
    for row in data:
        f.write(",".join(str(x) for x in row[1:3]))
        f.write("\n")
```

We get:

```
<coordinates>
-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824
-77.05465973756702,38.87291016281703
-77.05315536854791,38.87053267794386
-77.05552622493516,38.868757801256
-77.05844056290393,38.86996206506943
-77.05788457660967,38.87253259892824
</coordinates>
```

This displays correctly in Google Earth.